# Git - how to diff changes *introduced* in a branch after multiple merges to and from master?

Tags: git, branch

Here's the scenario. When a member of my team starts to work on a feature we branch off `master` to create a `feature` branch. We then merge `master` into `feature` often (at least every few days) to keep it up to date. When the feature is complete, we do a code review and make any changes necessary, and then merge `feature` into `master`. The code review process is: merge `master` into `feature` to be sure it's up to date, then `diff master feature` to see the whole set of feature code changes which can be reviewed nicely.

The above works well, but requires the whole code review process to be done *before* merging `feature` to `master`. Unfortunately the project schedule sometimes demands that we merge `feature` to `master` as soon as it's implemented so that the test team can begin testing it, and we must do code review *after* its been merged to master. This pre-review merge to `master` sometimes happens multiple times as pieces of the feature get finished.

Here is an example timeline of events:

1. Branch `feature` off from `master`.
2. Make changes on `feature`.
3. Merge `master` into `feature` to bring it up to date.
4. Make more changes on `feature`.
5. Merge `feature` to `master` so it can be tested.
6. Make more changes on `feature`.
7. Merge `master` into feature to bring it up to date.
8. Merge `feature` into `master` so it can be tested.
9. `feature` is now ready for code review.

My question is: how can `feature` be reviewed? Specifically, how can I isolate a line-by-line "diff" of all code changes that were **introduced** on `feature` (but now also exist in `master`) without seeing changes that were introduced elsewhere (but now also exist in `feature`)? Multiple merges have occurred between `master` and `feature` in both directions.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately the project schedule sometimes demands that we merge feature to master as soon as it's implemented so that the test team can begin testing it,

Can't you `git checkout -b test-feature-as-of-x master; git merge feature` and your testing team can bang on `test-feature-as-of-x` without polluting the `master` history with code that's going to get rejected?

Anyhoo, to find the oldest merge base from an upstream,

```
oldest-base() {
        ( git rev-list --first-parent $1; git rev-list --first-parent $2 ) \
        | awk 'seen[$1]++ { print;exit }'
}
```

and then `oldest-base feature master` to find the original master commit feature was branched from. To see all the changes in `feature` without the `master` stuff getting in the way you can

```
git checkout -b review `oldest-base feature master`
git cherry-pick -n --first-parent --no-merges ..feature
```

and that will bring in only the feature first-parent commits, stripping out all the merges from master.

Comment: Yes, merging un-reviewed code to master is very risky and not ideal, but it's not going to get rejected. The devs must do some initial testing before saying the feature is complete, and the test team tests many features at once so sadly individual branch testing isn't feasible. Hopefully we can convince management to get out of this "fast paced" mode of operation soon, and go back to conducting code reviews before merging to master. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you're collecting horribly long first-parent histories a more-efficient oldest-base finder would be `git rev-list --first-parent --parents $1 $2 | awk '++seen[$2] == 2 { print $2; exit }'` might save you a few tenths of a second here and there.

Answer (score 0):

The moment you merge feature into master, there's not much you can do to separate the changes from one branch or the other. If you *do not* merge feature into master, the way to do it is:

```
git diff master...feature # notice 3 dots
```

I said: If you *do not* merge feature into master. Merges of master into feature are OK and the diff works.